If A is idempotent then A+AB−ABA isidempotent for any square matrix B with the same dimension as A.

If A is idempotent then A+AB−ABA is idempotent for any square matrix B with the same dimension as A.

I have this question to solve and I tried squaring the entire expression and then simplifying it but it never gives me the answer I'm looking for. And I have no clue how to approach this proof.

This isn’t a hard problem. Your approach (squaring and simplifying) is correct, but you have probably made some mistakes in your computations. I suggest you to try again.

Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question + please avoid "no clue" questions: edit your post to include the details of your computations, so that we can help you to detect your mistake(s). I think you will benefit it more than reading @RobertIsrael's answer.

$$ (A + AB - ABA)(A + AB - ABA) =
  A (A + AB - ABA) + AB (A + AB - ABA) - ABA(A + AB - ABA)$$
Now $A (A + AB - ABA) = A + AB - ABA$ and
$ABA(A + AB - ABA) = AB (A + AB - ABA)$ because $A^2 = A$.
